# Launchpad Not Returning Results

Tags: business-objects

In my universe, apart from all other tables, there are 2 tables to which my question refers: 'Contract' and 'Address'. 
They are connected with 0,1 (Contract) to 1,n (Address) connection.
If in the Launchpad I select all attributes from both tables and press on 'Regenerate', I get no rows as a result. The question is why is this happening when I have clearly defined OUTER JOIN on Contract tables between these two tables.
However, when I analyse the generated query and when I run that query in database tool, I get 13,5 million rows. This result was even more surprising. Can anybody please explain why?
Finally, when inside the  Launchpad I click not on 'Regenarate' button, but on 'Start the Query' button, I get the following message: "No data available" (translation from German).
And this totally confused me.
My first thought was that maybe because of the large dataset (13,5 million rows) Launchpad denied to run the query. However, that does not explain why I got no rows when I clicked on 'Regenarate' button, because in that case I would have to get only 5000 rows as data preview.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Adam, are you running result for 5000 rows only? If so, may be in that 5000 rows there wont be result for the particular query. Also have tried refreshing again once you get 'no data available'?

Comment: I do not think that is the case, because when I run the same query not on LaunchPad but on IDT,I get the data preview. The only reasonable explanation from my viewpoint is that the resulting dataset is simply too big (13,5 million rows) for Launchpad.
I mean, who can make any normal use out of report with 13,5 million rows? Maybe if the end user wants to sum it up somehow, but then he should filter the query. 
Is my assumption correct, or is there a better explanation for the described behavour?